# PHP: Trying to upload multiple files, or a single file

Tags: php, file-upload

```
protected function upload($name) {

    $files = array();

    // if block 1
    if(!empty($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])) {

        for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']); $i++) {

            // if block #2
            if(!empty($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'][$i])) {

                # we're dealing with multiple uploads

                $handle['key']      = $name;
                $handle['name']     = $_FILES[$name]['name'][$i];
                $handle['size']     = $_FILES[$name]['size'][$i];
                $handle['type']     = $_FILES[$name]['type'][$i];
                $handle['tmp_name'] = $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'][$i];

                // put each array into the $files array
                array_push($files,$this->_process_image($handle));
            }

            #block 3...
        }

        return $files;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm trying to create a function that will handle multiple upload scenarios: multiple file uploads per submit, and one file upload per submit, using a variety of `file` inputs.

The above method...

works as expected with two inputs

```
<input name="multiple[]" type="file">
<input name="multiple[]" type="file">
```

and a single input using multiple...

```
<input name="multiple[]" type="file" multiple>
```

but not a single input using a single upload

```
<input name="single" type="file">
```

Now, I noticed that if I change the name of `single` to `single[]` it works. So I copied block #2 and added it as another block (where #3 is), but this time without using `[$i]` and it worked for the `single` input, but failed if i had multiple inputs but only used one input to upload one file (not uploading 2 files using both inputs).

My brain hurts. How can I get this to work for all these scenarios?

Edit: When I say it's not working, I mean it's not even processing. No output, no errors, nothing. I think it's just being skipped over, which is why I added block #3...

Comment: I dont understand, why you are struggling, here is the detailed documentation http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240

Comment: @SaiPhani I've been through all that. I'm not having trouble uploading multiple files, it's the _single_ file that's causing me grief with my code.

Comment: @Tim, when you have an array of files, why would you need a single file? The first element of the array would simply be the single file if there are no others.

Comment: There is different format of $_FILES array when uploading multiple files, or single file. Try something [like this](https://gist.github.com/umidjons/9893735) to normalize array.

Comment: @Tim , I see you are facing problem while sending single file. I doubt that your upload is not working proper for single file. In (file-upload.php) Try <?php vardump($_FILES)?> and check if you are able to receive the file you intent to upload.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath I'm creating a script that other people can use, so I have  to plan for all scenarios and can't count on somebody typing brackets in the `name` just for a single upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and it was really easy. I needed to check if the $_FILES array contained more than one file and process accordingly. probably a little bit more code than I'd like, but it's working exactly how I wanted.

```
protected function upload($name) {

    $files = array();

    if(!empty($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])) {

        # *** THIS IF BLOCK SOLVED THE PROBLEM ***
        # JUST CHECK IF $_FILES HAS MORE THAN ONE FILE
        if(count($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']) > 1) {

            for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']); $i++) {

                if(!empty($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'][$i])) {

                    # we're dealing with multiple uploads

                    $handle['key']      = $name;
                    $handle['name']     = $_FILES[$name]['name'][$i];
                    $handle['size']     = $_FILES[$name]['size'][$i];
                    $handle['type']     = $_FILES[$name]['type'][$i];
                    $handle['tmp_name'] = $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'][$i];

                    array_push($files,$this->_process_image($handle));
                }
            }

            return $files;

        } else {

            if(!empty($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])) {

                # we're handling a single upload

                $handle['key']      = $name;
                $handle['name']     = $_FILES[$name]['name'];
                $handle['size']     = $_FILES[$name]['size'];
                $handle['type']     = $_FILES[$name]['type'];
                $handle['tmp_name'] = $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'];

                return $this->_process_image($handle);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Send these files:
<br />
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" />
<br />
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send files" />
```

**PHP**(file-upload.php)

```
<?php

if ($_FILES['upload']) {
$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userfile']);

foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
if(intval($file['error'])==4){
   continue;
}
 //If you upload a single file this will execute only once
    print 'File Name: ' . $file['name'];
    print 'File Type: ' . $file['type'];
    print 'File Size: ' . $file['size'];
}
}
function reArrayFiles($file_post) {

$file_ary = array();
$file_count = count($file_post['name']);
$file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
    foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
        $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
    }
}

return $file_ary;
}
?>
```

Files Output :
[image]
[image]

Comment: This can handle both single and multi files

Comment: Using your code, I'm not getting anything like your output. This is what I'm getting when uploading a single file: `File Name: I`, `File Type: i`, `File Size: `

Comment: @Tim after $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userfile']); place this, echo "<pre>".print_r($file_ary ,true)."</pre>"; echo "<pre>".print_r($_FILES ,true)."</pre>"; and show me output

Comment: it's showing two arrays: [screenshot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=33nj5hf&s=8#.VSXK4s6RP8s)

Comment: @Tim it is uploading, replace "$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userfile']);"with "$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['file']);" and give me screen shot again

Comment: I changed the `file` element from `userfile` to `file` before sending the screenshot. If I were to send you another you'd get the exact same thing.

Comment: @Tim I can see that after `$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userfile']);` it is not changing file array as it supposed to. are you sure you copied above `function  reArrayFiles($file_post)` exactly